# Maven/Jenkins - Automatic releases of project and dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm working in maven project with several dependencies at several levels and each time a release of primary project is performed we have to create a lot of secondary releases manually. I will try to explain the situation.
My scenario is the following:

Project A

1. Dependency B

   - Dependency E
   - Dependency F

     - Dependency G
2. Dependency C

   - Dependency G

     - Dependency H
3. Dependency D

Each dependency is an independent maven project and it exists a lot of dependency levels inside projects. If you modify some code of dependency G and your intention is to generate Project A release you have to:

1. Generate release of project G
2. Update dependency G version on project F
3. Generate release of project F
4. Update dependency F version on project B
5. Generate release of project B
6. Update dependency B version on project A
7. Generate release of project A

My intention is to automate this process. I didn't find any similar question after googling it for several days.

Can you think in some solution for automatizing the task of generating releases in cascade?
I'm thinking in a solution based on maven and Jenkins tasks but it looks like very complex.

Comment: Can I ask how A, B, F & G relate to each other? Are some libraries and some services? Can A, B, F & G ever be released independently? Do any of the projects have compile time dependencies? Do any of the projects have only runtime dependencies?

Comment: Also what does it mean to "release" and do you also "deploy" and is that different? For example are these 'releases' just making an artifact that goes into something like nexus or do these releases actually deploy to servers?

Comment: Also is it always the case that these must always be released in this manner? Or is it the case that sometimes they are released independently (as microservices and libraries) yet sometimes they must be released as an arbitrary set. For example updating cross cutting security or logging across many things that usually deploy independently but today must be released together?

Comment: Note there is now a devops.stackexchange.com site in beta were this question might attract more attention of people that have experience of this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a combination of [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) and [Maven Release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) to release your Maven projects.

The Build Flow plugin will help you to design your build sequence (and respects your project dependencies).

It's just an idea, I didn't test this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins you can use different repositories to download and make the build, in this case you will perform a release. Hope you are using **maven-release-plugin**. So, you can use this jenkins's feature to download all the projects you mentioned and create or download the pom.xml file from the repo which contains each project as a module (Just to achieve your goal).

Structure in jenkins's workspace should looks like this:

- pom.xml
- moduleA
      pom.xml
- moduleB
      pom.xml
- moduleC
      pom.xml

My advice is to group them in a repository if is needed.